# Installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside with latest Windows 10 , PC machine booting straight into windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on PC machine alongside with latest Windows 10 OS .
Once installation of the Ubuntu is successfully and completed then I need to re-boot the PC machine due to complete installation process . However once the PC machine is switched on the machine is booting up straight into  the Windows 10 OS and will not give me any chance to pick up the OS which I wish to use currently .
Fast Boot disabled  , Secure boot disabled , Legacy is Enabled .

Long time ago I was play with oldest Ubuntu versions on my previously PC machine with Windows Vista and there were always a GRUB pre-installed which allowed me to choose different OS .

In recent machine there all is  messed up and I can't figure out what I should to do in order to get the GRUB and have ability to choice demanded OS during booting process .

I'm not good enough with a Linux but I keep trying with it as I feel it is really great thing to play with . Would be any one of you guys patient enough to explain me what to do in order to get things right .Please .

My PC Machine is HP Envy 700 , with one HDD (Windows 10 alongside with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS )

Thank you so much for any suggestion . Thank you !

Comment: Why legacy? Was Windows installed in that mode? Certainly not if factory installed.

Comment: Well , I had to enabled legacy support and disabled secure boot in order to boot ubuntu from CD rom , that why I mentioned it in previously post .

Comment: That's just plain d... Use an USB and always install in the same mode. Factory installed Windows 8 or newer is always UEFI, so there. Start by disabling CSM/Legacy at UEFI settings so that everything you boot after that will be running in UEFI mode. If you must (you do) read this meanwhile: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI .

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too....I went to boot bios for my laptop and changed the boot options. still the same problem.

I wiped the hard drive clean then redownloaded iso ubuntu then used rufus to convert to boot-able usb but ticked the bios boot option then followed the recommended settings after that.

Then had to change the laptop setting to boot from the external hard drive and it worked.

when it first installs did you select the boot options?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/735188)

Comment: oh well, just trying to help. he did say thanks for ANY suggestions..the simple answer would be get to the boot bios wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that the windows boot manager has overridden the Linux grub. You can reinstall grub by booting into a liveCD or liveUSB of ubuntu and then downloading and installing a software called boot-repair. Or you can go the terminal way.
Details on how to do that can be found in this link: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)